# Master branch analysis with Sonarqube (Community Edition)

Tags: sonarqube

I understand that it is possible to perform the analysis of the master branch with the Community version.

How can this be done? Since the only way I've found is using the sonar-scanner.

Thanks.

Comment: at [the docs you will find everything what you need] (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)
 - create `sonar.properties` including specific values, or pass parameters to the scanner by command link directly as its shown on [advanced scanner usage docs page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages) `sonar.host.url` is also important - you need to align sonarqube machine properly. The most important is eg. `sonar.projectkey` which needs to be matched with sonarqube project key- in case of maven plugin `groupID:artifactID`

Answer (score 8):

Sonarqube supports scanning of a branch per project in the Community Edition without any additional plugins installed. You typically do this using the scanner that fits into your build tool, e.g. [Sonar Maven Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven), [Sonar Gradle Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle), [Sonar MSBuild Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) plus some [other scanners](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN). You'll need to have a SonarQube server running somewhere (locally, or potentially Sonar Cloud) for the Scanner to communicate with.

The terminology may be what's misleading you here - SonarQube is split into 3 main parts:

- Sonar Server: the user interface and API, typically run on a remote server
- Sonar Scanner: the part that runs on your local/build machine, gathers details about your source code, libraries, test results, coverage etc and submits them to the Compute Engine
- Sonar Compute Engine: the part that does all the work of analysing source and byte code, coverage, and test results to calculate any issues and produce quality metrics which Sonar Server then presents back as the result of a scan. This part is normally run as part of you launching Sonar Server so you wont typically have to do anything special to get this working.

You wont be able to get any results without having used all 3 of these parts, normally by downloading and running SonarQube, and then running the scanner using your build tool.

If you're wanting to scan more than a single branch in newer editions of SonarQube (7.3 and above) then you'll need to consider updating to SonarQube Developer Edition, or installing a plugin that support [Community Edition Branch Analysis](https://github.com/mc1arke/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin)